# pow should be able to handle things like this: why does my code freeze at this point?

Tags: c, double, pow

So, my code can't get beyond this line:

```
double correction = ((double) (1/(1 + pow(2, ((double) ((popsize - maxpop)/maxpop)))))) + 0.5;
```

`popsize` is an `int`, and `maxpop` is a `long int`, defined by the user and limited to values between 1 and 10,000 and 1 and 500,000 respectively (though I may in the future set a higher limit on `maxpop`, which is why it's a `long int` in advance). I realize that most of those `double`'s are redundant, but I wanted to remain sure. The code compiles without any warnings, but once it actually gets to *running* this, it hangs. I tried printing out `correction` directly after it was declared, but not even that ran because it was stuck on that line. Also, don't worry, I didn't forget to include `math.h` (though I did at first, and had the same problem with an additional implicit declaration error). What's going wrong?

EDIT: Here is all my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

long double randomDouble() {
    long double r = (long double)rand()/(long double)RAND_MAX;
    return r;
}

int tryBernoulli(long double p) {
    if ((long double)rand()/(long double)RAND_MAX < p) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}

int tryRademacher() {
    if (rand() % 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int calculateSeries(int arg) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= arg; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    long double allp [1001] [33];
    long double p [33] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int allalsum [33] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int alsum [33] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int nalsum [33] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    long double selection [33] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int allgenotypes [467];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 465; i++) {
        allgenotypes[i] = 0;
    }
    int genotypes [467];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 465; i++) {
        genotypes[i] = 0;
    }
    int a,b; // The two alleles generated during generation for a single organism.
    int temp; // A temporary variable to store numbers in.
    long double randdbl = 0; // The number that randomDouble generates.
    int randint = 0; // A random integer (for safekeeping).
    int alnum = 2;
    int popsize = 1;
    int npopsize = 0;
    long int maxpop = 0;
    int gens = 1;
    long double fsum = 0; // For keeping track of what part of the probability distro you're in.
    int isum = 0; // For keeping track of what part of the gene pool you're in.
    int input = 0;
    long double finput = 0;
    long int linput = 0;
    printf("Hello! Welcome to Mike's Glorious Evolutionary Modeler. This models the genetic drift of a single gene in a population of arbitrary size. For a sufficiently large population, you should get no drift at all! To start, specify the starting population size (from 1 to 10,000, no commas please):\n");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    if (input < 1 || input > 10000) {
        while (input < 1 || input > 10000) {
            printf("That was outside of the limits (1 to 10,000)! Try again:\n");
            scanf("%d",&input);
        }
    }
    popsize = input;
    printf("\nAnd give the environmental population cap (between 1 and 500,000):\n");
    scanf("%ld",&linput);
    if (input < 1 || linput > 500000) {
        while (input < 1 || linput > 500000) {
            printf("That was outside of the limits (1 to 500,000)! Try again:\n");
            scanf("%ld",&linput);
        }
    }
    maxpop = linput;
    printf("\nNext, tell me how many alleles you would like (between 2 and 32):\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if (input < 2 || input > 32) {
        while (input < 2 || input > 32) {
            printf("That was outside of the limits (2 to 32)! Try again:\n");
            scanf("%d",&input);
        }
    }
    alnum = input;
    printf("\nTime to specify the probabilities of all of the alleles (except the last one)! Specify each, up to four decimal places. They have to add up to 1. ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= (alnum-1); i++) {
        printf("Please enter the probability of Allele %d, denoted A%d (between 0 and %Lf, inclusive):\n", i, i, (1-fsum));
        scanf("%Lf",&finput);
        if (fsum + finput > 1) {
            while (fsum + finput > 1) {
                printf("That put the sum over 1! Try again:\n");
                scanf("%Lf",&finput);
            }
        }
        p[i-1] = finput;
        fsum = fsum + finput;
        printf("Now please enter the selection coefficient for Allele %d. If you want the population growth to remain at 0, set it to 1. In order to maintain a reasonable growth rate, this coefficient may be no more than 1.1.\n", i);
        scanf("%Lf",&finput);
        if (finput < 0 || finput > 1.1) {
            while (finput < 0 || finput > 1.1) {
                printf("Nice try. It should be between 0 and 1.1.\n");
                scanf("%Lf",&finput);
            }
        }
        selection[i-1] = finput;
    }
    fsum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= (alnum-1); i++) {
        fsum = fsum + p[i-1];
    }
    p[alnum-1] = 1 - fsum;
    printf("Okay, the probability for A%d will be %Lf. What should its selection coefficient be?\n",alnum,p[alnum-1]);
    scanf("%Lf",&finput);
    if (finput <= 0 || finput > 1.1) {
        while (finput <= 0 || finput > 1.1) {
            printf("Nice try. It should be between 0 and 1.1.\n");
            scanf("%Lf",&finput);
        }
    }
    selection[alnum-1] = finput;
    printf("\nOkay! Enter the amount of generations that the calculations should be done for (between 1 and 1,000):\n");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    if (input < 1 || input > 1000) {
        while (input < 1 || input > 1000) {
            printf("That was outside of the limits (1 to 1,000)! Try again:\n");
            scanf("%d",&input);
        }
    }
    gens = input;
    printf("Okay! Ready to go. Give me a moment...\n\n");
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL)); // Seed the generator. Only do this once!
    for (int j = 0; j <= popsize-1; j++) { // This part generates and files the alleles and genotypes of the first generation.
        randdbl = randomDouble();
        fsum = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k <= alnum-1; k++) {
            if (randdbl > fsum && randdbl < fsum + p[k]) {
                a = k+1;
                break;
            }
            fsum = fsum + p[k];
        }
        randdbl = randomDouble();
        fsum = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k <= alnum-1; k++) {
            if (randdbl > fsum && randdbl < fsum + p[k]) {
                b = k+1;
                break;
            }
            fsum = fsum + p[k];
        }
        if (a > b) {
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        allalsum[a-1]++;
        allalsum[b-1]++;
        alsum[a-1]++;
        alsum[b-1]++;
        if (b == a) {
            if (b == 1) {
                genotypes[0]++;
            } else {
                genotypes[calculateSeries(b)-b]++;
                allgenotypes[calculateSeries(b)-b]++;
            }
        } else {
            genotypes[calculateSeries(b-1)+a]++;
            allgenotypes[calculateSeries(b-1)+a]++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nStatistics for Generation 1:\n Population: %d\n Number of Genotype:\n", popsize);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= alnum-1; i++) {
        printf("  A%dA%d: %d\n",(i+1),(i+1),genotypes[index]);
        index++;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("  A%dA%d: %d\n",j,(i+1),genotypes[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n Number of Allele:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= alnum-1; i++) {
        printf("  A%d: %d\n",(i+1),alsum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n Percent Allele Composition:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= alnum-1; i++) {
        allp [gens] [i] = p[i]; // Store old probability values in array
        p[i] = ((long double) alsum[i])/((long double) (2*popsize)); // Generate new ones from current generation
        printf("  A%d: %Lf%%\n",(i+1),(p[i]*100));
    }
    // Clean up:
    for (int j = 0; j <= 465; j++) {
        genotypes[j] = 0;
    }
    /********************************************************************************************************
     ************************************************IMPORTANT***********************************************
     ********************************************************************************************************/
    for (int i = 2; i <= gens; i++) { // This part calculates the values for all the rest of the generations.
        double correction = ((double) (1/(1 + pow(2, ((double) ((popsize - maxpop)/maxpop)))))) + 0.5; // The logistic function that curves the population growth with respect to the population cap.
        for (int j = 0; j <= (alnum-1); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= alsum[j]; k++) {
                while (tryBernoulli(((0.5+correction)*selection[j]))) {
                    nalsum[j]++;
                }
            }
        }
        popsize = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= (alnum-1); j++) {
            popsize = popsize+nalsum[j];
        }
        if ((popsize % 2) == 1) {
            popsize--;
            nalsum[rand()%alnum]--;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= (alnum-1); j++) {
            alsum[j] = nalsum[j];
            allalsum[j] = allalsum[j] + nalsum[j];
        }
        if (popsize == 0) {
            printf("\nOops! Your population has died out!");
            break;
        }
        npopsize = popsize/2;
        while (npopsize != 0) {
            isum = alsum[0];
            randint = rand()%popsize;
            for (int j = 0; j <= (alnum-1); j++) {
                if (nalsum[j] > 0) {
                    if (randint <= isum) {
                        a = j + 1;
                        nalsum[j]--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                isum = isum + alsum [j+1];
            }
            isum = alsum[0];
            randint = rand()%popsize;
            for (int j = 0; j <= (alnum-1); j++) {
                if (nalsum[j] > 0) {
                    if (randint <= isum) {
                        b = j + 1;
                        nalsum[j]--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                isum = isum + alsum [j+1];
            }
            if (b == a) {
                if (b == 1) {
                    genotypes[0]++;
                } else {
                    genotypes[calculateSeries(b)-b]++;
                    allgenotypes[calculateSeries(b)-b]++;
                }
            } else {
                genotypes[calculateSeries(b-1)+a]++;
                allgenotypes[calculateSeries(b-1)+a]++;
            }
            npopsize--;
        }
        popsize = popsize/2;
        printf("\nStatistics for Generation %d:\n Population: %d\n Number of Genotype:\n",i,popsize);
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= alnum-1; j++) {
            printf("  A%dA%d: %d\n",(j+1),(j+1),genotypes[index]);
            index++;
            for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++) {
                printf("  A%dA%d: %d\n",k,(j+1),genotypes[index]);
                index++;
            }
        }
        printf("\n Number of Allele:\n");
        for (int j = 0; j <= alnum-1; j++) {
            printf("  A%d: %d\n",(j+1),alsum[j]);
        }
        printf("\n Percent Allele Composition:\n");
        for (int j = 0; j <= alnum-1; j++) {
            /*allp [gens] [j] = p[j]; // Store old probability values in array */
            p[j] = ((long double) alsum[j])/((long double) (2*popsize)); // Generate new ones from current generation
            printf("  A%d: %Lf%%\n",(j+1),(p[j]*100));
        }
        // Clean up:
        for (int j = 0; j <= 465; j++) {
            genotypes[j] = 0;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= 31; j++) {
            nalsum[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    /*printf("\nGraph of Total Amounts of Each Genotype (one # represents 10):\n");
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= alnum-1; i++) {
        printf("  A%dA%d: ",(i+1),(i+1));
        for (int j = 0; j < (allgenotypes[index]/10); j++) {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
        index++;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("  A%dA%d: ",j,(i+1));
            for (int k = 0; k <= (allgenotypes[index]/10); k++) {
                printf("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
            index++;
        }
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Q: What compiler?  OS?  Are you *sure* it's hanging on that particular line???

Comment: Are you sure it's not division by 0? Or division of `INT_MIN`/`LONG_MIN` by -1?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's that line, since nothing even prints after it... this is the latest version of Xcode (which uses gcc I believe???) on Mac OS X 10.7.whatever.

Comment: And I'm very sure it's not division by zero, since `maxpop` has always been able to be defined (and it's not allowed to be defined as 0) and the `pow` function has been tested in multiple cases and can't equal -1 ever in any case anyway, and it would give a division by zero error if it did. EDIT: please explain `division of INT_MIN/LONG_MIN by -1`

Comment: Can't reproduce with Linux/gcc, it compiles and makes it past that line fine.

Comment: You should post completely runnable code so that other people can test it. It is extremely unlikely your code is hanging in `pow`. Failing to display output from a printf or similar call just after this statement does not show the program hung at your statement. More likely, it indicates your program hung before the output buffer was flushed. (You could try adding `fflush(stdout)` after the printf to test this.) Thus, shortly after this, your program may hang. Running it in a debugger, then interrupting it after the hang and using the debugger to display the program location could be useful.

Comment: Q: Yes, I'm sure it's that line, since nothing even prints after it...   SUGGESTION: instead of "`printf()`", use "`fprintf(stderr, ...)`".  Stderr (unlike stdout) uses non-buffered I/O.  In my experience, "fprintf (stderr)" is easier to type and more effective than the extra "fflush (stdout)".  IMHO...

Comment: The debugger gives `correction = (double) 0`... lemme post my code...

(also I'm trying to avoid `fflush(stdout)` because this has to be run up to a thousand times in a row)

Comment: `fflush(stdout)` doesn't work. Curious that `correction` is `0`, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
((popsize - maxpop)/maxpop)
```

is going to be zero whenever `maxpop` is greater than `popsize`.  If you're interested in fractional powers, you're going to need to convert to double sooner.

A value of zero shouldn't cause a freeze, though.  Did you include `<math.h>`? (Yes: you say as much in the question.) <s>If not, then you've got more problems; the first argument should be an explicit double.</s>

You could sensibly write:

```
double correction = 1.0 / (1.0 + pow(2.0, ((double)popsize - maxpop)/maxpop)) + 0.5;
```

That's far more readable because there are fewer parentheses and fewer casts.

Have you tried printing the various values at the point of the freeze?  If you're not sure why something is going wrong, one of the first things to do is to make sure you know what values you're working with.

Comment: Thanks, this at least prints now. I now think I know why the program's hanging... it's because it's followed immediately by a while loop that generates a number between 0 and 1 and only stops when it's over `correction`, and `correction` comes out to over 1 here for some reason Thanks, I'll go tweak the math. EDIT: Aaaaaaaand it should've 8een `- 0.5`. Well. That'll certainly teach me. I can't get my coordinate transformations right ever...

Comment: I was getting a freeze in your full code because of the loop calling `tryBernoulli()` with a value `p = 1.575000`, which will cause `tryBernoulli()` to always return 1, leading to a rather long running time.  Glad to have helped.

Comment: The information about hanging in the loop with `tryBernoulli` should be moved into this or another answer. The problem has nothing to do with `pow`.

Answer (score 2):

This executes instantly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  double popsize = 50;
  double maxpop = 100;
  double correction =
    ((double)(1/(1 + pow(2, ((double) ((popsize - maxpop)/maxpop)))))) + 0.5;
  printf ("correction= %f\n", correction);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled and linked as follows (CentOS Linux 5.5, GCC 4.1.2):

`gcc -Wall -pedantic tmp.c -o tmp -lm`

Here's the times (an eyeblink):

```
 time ./tmp
correction= 1.085786

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Q: What's your OS and compiler?

Q: Do you need to explicitly link the math library ("-lm") on your platform?